# sort int string java

Tags: java, sorting

My TXT file contains these:

> Škoda Fábia
> farba: Červená
> 05050
>
> Škoda Fábia
> farba: Metalíza
> 53498
>
> Škoda Fábia
> farba: Metalíza
> 46538
>
> Škoda Fábia
> farba: Červená
> 21849
>
> Škoda Fábia
> farba: Biela
> 10219

How can it be sorted by numbers, so that these 3 informations aren't separated?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Slanec, how did you guess the formatting? Perhaps the file really was as ugly as originally presented...

Comment: @sarnold Um. Good point. It's true I _guessed_ it based on the comment there. It was too eager, wasn't I? Tomas, is this formatiing the one you intended by the comment, or is it not?

Comment: @Slanec: Aha, I had assumed that was part of the contents, too. Then you're probably right...

Comment: well, that was my first post here, and it does look like the original file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons for this question getting downvoted are:

1. [There's no effort shown. Tell us what you've tried and what you know.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128553#128553)
2. We love code. Please show us your code. Even the non-working one.
3. If one thinks about the problem for a while, unanswered questions begin to pop up. For example:

   - Do all the numbers have 6 digits?
   - If not, is `05050` less or more than `5051`?

That said, here's your answer:

1. Read the cars into some sort of structure. A `Car` class would be perfect (could have its own `compareTo()` method if this kind of sort is the only useful one). Or just use a `String[]` for each car, therefore ending up with an array of cars (`String[][]`).
2. Sort them like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29) if they're [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29) using a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

An example (use a `SkodaCar` class instead of that `String[]` thing if you can):

```
// every car is a String[3]
String[][] cars = loadCars();
Comparator<String[]> skodaCarComparator = new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
        // compares the numbers as Strings using String's compareTo()
        return o1[2].compareTo(o2[2]);
    }
}; 
Arrays.sort(cars, skodaCarComparator);
```